# How to use rescue when a LoadError is raised

Tags: ruby, error-handling, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to implement a file dialog using Tk. This aspect has worked but my error checking isn't working.

Since this file dialog can only take certain extensions I made it raise a LoadError, but I also don't want the program to stop, I want it to reopen to allow the user to pick another file.

Each way I've tried has only ended in an infinite loop or a LoadError stopping the program.

My code is:

```
module FileExplorer
  require 'tk'
  require 'tkextlib/tile'

  def self.fileDialog
    TkClipboard.append(Tk.getOpenFile)
    f = TkClipboard.get
    begin
      unless extenstionCheck(f)
        raise LoadError, 'Please select a valid file type'
      end
    rescue LoadError
      fileDialog
    end
  end

  def self.extenstionCheck(file)
    filetypes = ['.xlsx', '.xls', '.csv', '.xml']
    type = File.extname(file)
    true if filetypes.include?(file)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use TkClipboard, nor to use an exception.

Did misspelling the word, 'extension' blind you to your nearby error of checking whether `filetypes` included `file`, instead of `type`?

Your program, minimally changed as follows, works for me:

```rb
module FileExplorer
  require 'tk'
  require 'tkextlib/tile'

  def self.fileDialog
    while true
      f = Tk.getOpenFile
      break if extension_okay?(f)
      Tk.messageBox message: 'Please select a valid file type!', detail: "Selection was: #{f}"
    end
    f
  end

  def self.extension_okay?(file)
    filetypes = ['.xlsx', '.xls', '.csv', '.xml']
    type = File.extname(file)
    filetypes.include?(type)
  end
end
p FileExplorer.fileDialog
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely inappropriate (and unnecessary) use of [LoadError](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/LoadError.html).

> Raised when a file required (a Ruby script, extension library, …)
>   fails to load.

Its a low level error that does not inherit from StandardError and is tied to [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require).

Instead declare your own exceptions in your own namespace:

```
module FileExplorer
  require 'tk'
  require 'tkextlib/tile'
  FileTypeError = Class.new(::StandardError)

  def self.fileDialog
    TkClipboard.append(Tk.getOpenFile)
    f = TkClipboard.get
    begin
      unless extenstionCheck(f)
        raise FileTypeError, 'Please select a valid file type'
      end
    rescue FileTypeError
      fileDialog
    end
  end

  def self.extenstionCheck(file)
    filetypes = ['.xlsx', '.xls', '.csv', '.xml']
    type = File.extname(file)
    true if filetypes.include?(file)
  end
end
```